# auto-rotating a jq.carousel using setInterval, and pausing on hover

Tags: jquery, setinterval, carousel

I'm using [jq.carousel](http://5509.github.com/jq.carousel/#sample) and as it doesn't have an auto-rotate function built in I'm using setInterval to advance it every second by calling `$carouselHome.carousel('next')`.

This works, but I need to add 'pause on hover'. Here's what I have so far which works as required only after the mouse has entered and left the element once. How would I 'kick off' the interval on first page load? (example: http://jsfiddle.net/meredevelopment/hmUbd/)

```
var $carouselHome = $('#carousel-home').carousel();

$('#carousel-home_prev').on('click', function(ev) {
    $carouselHome.carousel('prev');
});

$('#carousel-home_next').on('click', function(ev) {
    $carouselHome.carousel('next');
});

/*setInterval(function() {
    $carouselHome.carousel('next');
}, 1000);*/

$("#carousel-home").mouseenter(function(){
    clearInterval($(this).data('timeoutId'));
}).mouseleave(function(){
    var someElement = $(this);
    var timeoutId = setInterval(function() {
        $carouselHome.carousel('next');
    }, 1000);
    console.log(timeoutId);
    someElement.data('timeoutId', timeoutId); 
});
```

Thanks!
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
if ($("#carousel-home").length > 0) {
    var $carouselHome = $('#carousel-home').carousel();

    var timeoutId = setInterval(function() {
       $carouselHome.carousel('next');
    }, 1000);

    $('#carousel-home_prev').on('click', function(ev) {
        $carouselHome.carousel('prev');
    });
    $('#carousel-home_next').on('click', function(ev) {
        $carouselHome.carousel('next');
    });

    $("#carousel-home").mouseenter(function() {
        clearInterval(timeoutId);
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        var someElement = $(this);
        timeoutId = setInterval(function() {
            $carouselHome.carousel('next');
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ninja Pants Man... thats great :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with!

```
if ($("#carousel-home").length > 0){
    var $carouselHome = $('#carousel-home').carousel();
    $('#carousel-home_prev').on('click', function(ev) {
    $carouselHome.carousel('prev');
    });
    $('#carousel-home_next').on('click', function(ev) {
        $carouselHome.carousel('next');
    });

    function rotateMe() {$carouselHome.carousel('next');}

    var timer = setInterval( rotateMe, 4000);

    $('#carousel-home, #carousel-home_next, #carousel-home_prev').hover(function(ev){
        clearInterval(timer);
    }, function(ev){
        timer = setInterval( rotateMe, 4000);
    });
}
```

The next and previous buttons were added to the 'hover' pause, and also I used `.hover` when I saw that it could toggle an 'un-hover' function too. simpler I think.